# Solve *sparse* upper triangular system

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, triangular

If I want to solve a *full* upper triangular system, I can call `linsolve(A,b,'UT')`. However this currently is not supported for sparse matrices. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Use [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html)?

Comment: @chaohuang A very bad idea. He uses `sparse` for a reason.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** Since what you need is a triangular solve procedure, also called backward/forward substitution, you can use ordinary MATLAB backslash `\` operator for that:

```
x = U\b
```

As mentioned in the original answer, MATLAB will recognise the fact that your matrix is triangular. To be sure of that, you can compare the performance to `cs_usolve` procedure found in [SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/). It is a mex function implemented in C that computes sparse triangular solve for upper-triangular sparse matrix (there are similar functions there too: `cs_lsolve`, `cs_utsolve` and `cs_ltsolve`).

You can have a look at a [performance comparison](http://milamin.sourceforge.net/technical-notes/forward-and-backward-substitution) of native MATLAB and `cs_l(t)solve` in the context of sparse Cholesky factorization. Essentially, MATLAB performance is good. The only pitfall is if you want to solve a transposed system

```
x = U'\b
```

MATLAB does **not** recognize that and explicitly creates a transpose of `U`. In that case you should call `cs_utsolve` explicitly.

**Original answer** If your system is symmetric and you only store the upper triangular matrix part (that is how I understood *full* in your question), and if Cholesky decomposition is suitable for you, [chol](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) handles symmetric matrices, if your matrix is positive definite. For indefinite matrices you can use [ldl](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html). Both handle sparse storage and work on the symmetric matrix parts.

Newer matlab versions use [cholmod and suitesparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/) for that. That is by far the best performing Cholesky factorization I know of. In matlab it is also parallelised usin parallel BALS.

The factor you obtain from the above functions is upper triangular matrix L such that

```
A=LL'
```

All you need to do now is perform forward and backward substitution, which is simple and cheap. In matlab this is automatically done in tha backslash operator

```
x=L'\(L\b)
```

the matrix can be sparse, and matlab will recognise that it is upper/lower triangular. You would also use this call together with forward substitution for factors obtained using the cholesky factorization.

Comment: I think he means `A = triu(...)` (full) vs `A = sparse(triu(...))` (sparse)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Oh, now I read it again I think you are right. But my answer anyway includes information about triangular solves (backward/forward substitution) - in the end this is what you do after you factorize your matrix anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

UT and LT systems are amongst the easiest systems to solve. Have a read [on the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution) about it. Knowing this, it is easy to write your own UT or LT solver:

```
%# some example data
A = sparse( triu(rand(100)) );
b = rand(100,1);

%# solve UT system by back substitution    
x = zeros(size(b));
for n = size(A,1):-1:1    
    x(n) = (b(n) - A(n,n+1:end)*x(n+1:end) ) / A(n,n);    
end
```

The procedure is quite similar for LT systems.

Having said that, it is generally much easier and faster to use Matlab's backslash operator:

```
x = A\b
```

which also works for spares matrices, as nate already indicated.

Note that this operator also solves UT systems which have non-square `A` or if `A` has some elements equal to zero (or `< eps`) on the main diagonal. It solves these cases in a least-squares sense, which may or may not be desirable for you. You could check for these cases before carrying out the solve:

```
if size(A,1)==size(A,2) && all(abs(diag(A)) > eps)
    x = A\b;
else
    %# error, warning, whatever you want
end
```

Read more about the (back)slash operator by typing

```
>> help \
```

or

```
>> help slash
```

on the Matlab command prompt.

Comment: Of course I can implement that back substitution myself, I thought that is obvious :) the problem is that for-loops are generally avoided in matlab as they are very slow. 
Is the slash operation guaranteed to use back substitution for triangular matrices?

Comment: @noam: Have a look [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices).

Comment: \ is a backslash , or left division (`mldivide`), while `/`is a slash, or right division (`mrdivide`).

Comment: You used word `slash` for \, which is `backslash`. Just to be picky ;)

Comment: @angainor: Have you typed `help backslash`? you'll get an error. Type `help slash` and you get info on all (back)slash operators :)

Comment: I am referring to the line `Having said that, it is generally much easier and faster to use Matlab's slash operator: x=A\b`. This is in fact a backslash..

Answer (score 1):

you can use MLDIVIDE( \ ) or MRDIVIDE( / ) operators on your sparse matrices...